# Returning *this

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, operators

I have a class which contains a array of some int. I want to overload * operator so it would multiplies every element by certain number. Class is very common.

```
class TEST{
public:
      TEST(){
        size = 5;
        arr = new double[size]();
      }
      double &operator [] ( const int a ){
        return arr[a];
      }

      TEST operator *( const int a ){
         for( int i = 0; i < size ;i++){
             arr[i] = arr[i] * a;
        }
        return *this;
     }   
private:
     int size;
     double *arr;
}
```

When i invoke it as

```
TEST one;
one[1]=5;
one[0]=-10;
one[3]=4
one = one * 2
```

and printing it , the value of result , the 0 index is always random number from memory , like it does not have 0 index ; this happens only after  `one = one * 2`. Is `*this` causing this? If so why and how can i fix it?

//
I have declared * as

```
TEST operator *( const int a ){
       TEST temp;
       for( int i = 0; i < size ;i++){
           temp.arr[i] = arr[i] * a;
       }
           return temp;
}
```

and declared copy constructor

```
TEST( const TEST &a){
        size    = a.size;
        arr     = new double;
        *arr    = *a.arr;
    }
```

And it still throws random nubmer as 0 index

Comment: How does this compile?  In your `operator` method, you use a variable `b` which is not defined.

Comment: And why don't you just declare your array as:
`double arr[5];`

Comment: What are you expecting `one[1]=5;` to do? What's the point of changing the value of a temporary that ceases to exist at the end of the statement? Also, do you really want an `operator *` that changes the value of the thing you apply it to? And since you have one, why `one = one * 2` -- why not just `one * 2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subscript operator should be defined the following way

```
  double & operator [] ( int a ){
    return arr[a];
  }
```

and

```
  double operator [] ( int a ) const {
    return arr[a];
  }
```

or

```
  const double & operator [] ( int a ) const {
    return arr[a];
  }
```

`operator *` should be defined the following way

```
     TEST operator *( int a ) const {
         TEST tmp;
         for( int i = 0; i < size ;i++){
             tmp.arr[i] = arr[i] * a;
        }
        return tmp;
     }
```

Or the declaration can look also like

```
const TEST operator *( int a ) const;
^^^^^
```

You need also to define at least (apart from the destructor and the copy constructor) the copy assignment operator explicitly.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

class TEST
{
public:
    TEST() : size( 5 ), arr( new double[size]() )
    {
    }

    ~TEST()
    {
        delete []arr;
    }        

    TEST & operator =( const TEST &rhs )
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < size ;i++ ) arr[i] = rhs.arr[i];

        return *this;
    }             

    double & operator [] ( int n )
    {
        return arr[n];
    }

    const double & operator [] ( int n ) const 
    {
        return arr[n];
    } 

    TEST operator *( int x ) const 
    {
        TEST tmp;

        for ( int i = 0; i < size ;i++ )
        {
            tmp.arr[i] = x * arr[i];
        }

        return tmp;
    }

    int count() const
    {
        return size;
    }        
 private:
    int size;
    double *arr;
};

int main()
{
    TEST one;
    one[1] = 5;
    one[0] =-10;
    one[3] = 4;
    one = one * 2;

    for( int i = 0; i < one.count() ;i++ ) std::cout << one[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Its output is

```
-20 10 0 8 0
```

**EDIT:** It is a bad idea that you changed your post after my answer using the code shown in my answer. Your copy constructor is invalid. It creates only one object of type double instead of an array.

Comment: why do i need to define copy constructor in this case?

Comment: lot of source indicate , that declaring copy constructor and copy assigment operator  are the same in usage. Why do i need to declare both? i have edited question for progress.

Comment: @owacoder My comment referred to an earlier version of the answer.

Comment: @user3706129 In general you need to define it. Otherwise you can not create one object of the class from another object of the class. As for your current code then you need to define the destructor and the copy assignment operator.

Comment: I see , to reffer my previous question , would the code behave the same if , instead of copy assigment operator , i declared copy constructor? If yes , i updated question for my copy constructor , which didnt help program at all.

Comment: @user3706129 Stop to change your question!  Your copy constructor is invalid and does not make sense.

Comment: @user3706129 If somebody has answered your question but you have another problem *ask another question*.  Please don't change the question to another one.